# Neither did Neither she nor he

Tags: neither-nor, either-any

We can say:

I didn't do it

Some other guy can say:

> Neither did I

And we get such a scheme of such negation:

"Neither" + "auxiliary verb" + noun

But what if to complex it a little:

> We talked with neither her nor him

How to say that they (she and him) didn't talk with us, either?

Is my variant correct?:

> "Neither" + did(auxiliary verb) + "neither she nor he"(noun)

Or it would be so:

> "Neither" + did(auxiliary verb) + "either she or he"(noun)

Answer (score 1):

We can follow 'neither' with two items, which are **joined** by 'nor'. I like neither hot dogs nor mustard; We talked with neither Mary nor Jim; Neither Peter nor Sarah likes hot dogs.

[“Nor” with “Neither”](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor)